# How can I take at most two arguments and choose a default if one is missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse arguments of my Python program and I want the format be like this:

`program --arg1 val1 val2`

There shouldn't be any more values for this argument, but it can be only one. So at most two values.

I also want to provide a default for the first value, `val1`, so that if it's missing, the default be used.

For example, these commands should work fine:

```
program --arg1 a b
# val1 = a
# val2 = b

program --arg1 a
# val1 = DEFAULT
# val2 = a
```

And these commands should produce an error:

```
program --arg1
program --arg1 a b c
```

For this purpose, there are two arguments provided in the library, [nargs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) and [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default).

`nargs` supports `N`, `+`, `*`, `?`, and `argparse.REMAINDER`. But none of these work for me, because `N` expects exactly N number of arguments and `nargs=2` will throw an error if I give it only one. The rest doesn't satisfy the requirement either.

And the `default` argument only works for positional arguments whose `nargs` is equal to `?` or `*`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Edit the `argparse.py` file to extend the `nargs` options to meet your needs. :)  I could point you to a Python bug/issue where I developed a `nargs` range option.  But if you aren't up for that, I'd suggest '+', along with a bit of  your own post-parsing processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` doesn't support every conceivable convention. The simplest thing to do would be to use `nargs='+'`, and post-process the resulting value.

```
p = ArgumentParser()

p.add_argument("--arg1", nargs='+')

args = p.parse_args()

if args.arg1 is not None:
    if len(args.arg1) == 1:
        val1 = DEFAULT
        val2 = args.arg1[0]
    elif len(args.arg1) == 2:
        val1, val1 = args.arg1
    else:
        raise ArgumentTypeError("--arg1 requires 1 or 2 arguments")
```

Note that the `default` argument to `add_argument` is used only if `--arg1` is not specified at all. In the above, I've assumed a default of `None`; adjust the check for `args.arg1` if necessary.

I would recommend parsing a single argument yourself, for example using a comma or a colon to separate the two values.

```
def one_or_two(s):
    values = s.split(",")  # or s.split(":"), etc
    if len(values) == 1:
        values.insert(0, "DEFAULT")
    return values[:2]

p.add_argument("--arg1", type=one_or_two)

args = p.parse_args()

if args.arg1 is not None:
    val1, val2 = args.arg1
```

or using a second option altogether that gets ignored if `--arg1` isn't used.

```
p.add_argument("--arg1")
p.add_argument("--arg2")

args = p.parse_args()
if args.arg1 is not None:
    if args.arg2 is not None:
        val1 = args.arg1
        val2 = args.arg2
    else:
        val1 = DEFAULT
        val2 = args.arg1
```